# Compare two integers with bitwise operation

Tags: bitwise-operators, arithmetic-expressions, constant-time

I saw a bunch of codes which can do simple arithmetic operations in constant-time.

But there is a code makes me curious.

Here is a code written in C.

```
int ct_lt_u32(uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
    return (x^((x^y)|((x-y)^y)))>>31;
}
```

This function returns 1 if `x<y`, 0 otherwise.

However, I cannot understand why this function works.
Can anyone help me to understand this function? There are only XOR, OR, shift and subtraction.

Comment: I am curious to know if this is the underlying implementation of the "less than operator" or is it just something built for fun.

Comment: Remember that if `x < y`, then `x-y` will have the sign bit set.  That's all this is doing, plus handling the corner cases for overflow.